# Disable key map in lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, shortcut-keys

The Lubuntu 16.04 keyboard shortcuts ctrl+alt+down and alt+shift+down are stepping on my sublime text keymaps.

Is there a way to disable these keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Keyboard#Create_New_Keyboard_shortcuts. If you can add keyboard shortcuts, you should be able to remove them too in a similar way.